# Get dropdown selected value to two textbox from database based on dropdown list selected value idin mvc4 jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using JSON for drop down list select value based on id have to insert in 2 textboxes from database 
where I use the code in jQuery

```
$("#Lt").change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("code", "Home")',  
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: $("#Lt").val() }),
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json,charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#AgreementSeries").val(data)
        }
    });
});
```

Here I have got one textbox value. How can I get another textbox value from the database?

My controller code is:

```
public JsonResult code(string id)
{
    string no;
    string series;
    int _id = Convert.ToInt32(id);
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT top(1) Agreementseries, num from loan where id = @ID", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", _id);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    series = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Agreementseries"].ToString();
    no = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["num"].ToString();
    return Json(series, no, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return a JSON object like

```
return Json(new {
                series =series, 
                no = no
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Which can be used like

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#AgreementSeries").val(data.series);
    //Use data.no as per your requirement
}
```

Comment: I got as u told like that Thanku so much